# i use android image slider inside github , but when run the app , its crashed

Tags: java, android, github, crash, androidimageslider

i added all dependencies to module app

Error:

```
 Could not find class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener

Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.dispatchApplyWindowInsets
 Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
```

my dependencies :

```
dependencies {
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
            implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
            implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
            implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
            implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
            implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5'
            implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0' 
        }
```

but has crashed

Comment: Please some code and detailed description of your problem.

Comment: i added now ...